# Death because of no radio waves

Tags: human-biology, physiology

I read somewhere that a man dies if he is isolated from natural electromagnetic fields and waves. (I imply fields of radio frequencies and below.)

Is it true?

Comment: note that visible light and infra-red are also EM waves. Humans can survive in total darkness for a while though....it would be pretty cold too!

Comment: @Memming: certainly light, UV, and infrared don't count in my question

Comment: what frequency of EM wave, then, are you talking about? Without the magnetic field of earth, there would be too much solar wind/cosmic ray as well.

Comment: @Memming: I am about radio frequencies and below. I do not ask on indirect effects of EM on survival of human (such as about Earth field protecting from Sun rays), only about direct effect of EM on human body.

Comment: I see. So less than GHz range? Could you update your question to clarify this? :)

Comment: I never heard of anybody dying in a Faraday cage, so I don't think lack of EM or natural electric field has any effect, at least short term.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on an unreferenced claim

Comment: @porton I think your right, we all know that every body above absolute zero dissipates energy as em waves, so if a person is isolated from all em waves it implies that there is no em wave coming to him, so the person dies because hi will be at absolute zero temperature at that moment. Hope it answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard of such a thing, and a quick Scholar search didn't yield anything significant. In fact, artificial radio waves are used in things that usually *save* lives, like MRIs.

If we were truly agnostic about this, we could say that it might or might not have an effect on human survival due to the general lack of evidence or even indication of a claim, but like [the orbiting teacup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_teapot), it's safe to assume that **given our current extensive set of knowledge of biology, radiowaves do not affect human at all, and that as it has not been observed, the claim doesn't have a scientific basis.**